# Some Byobu shortcuts not working when using the Secure Shell extension from a Chromebook

Tags: ssh, chrome-book, byobu

I'm using the [Secure Shell Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) to SSH  from a Chromebook to a Linux workstation. When I launch byobu (with the `tmux` backend), *most* of its keyboard shortcuts work fine, but a notable exception is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> for switching between sessions(*), which are interpreted as simple <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> key presses that scroll through my bash command history.

*How can I  switch between sessions on this environment?*

Ideally there's some combination of settings that would fix this, but I couldn't find the right incantation myself. I'm also interested in potential workarounds, like creating [new Byobu shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208369/modify-key-bindings-in-byobu) or using alternative [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-based byobu shortcuts](https://gist.github.com/PackeTsar/e4adf2a2056710a0b65c537fd2990188)?.

In case that helps, these are the sequences I get using `read -n 1` from the Secure Shell extension (which don't work with byobu):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: `^[[5~`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: `^[[6~`

And from a local terminal running directly on the workstation (which work as expected with byobu):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: `^[[1;3A`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: `^[[1;3B`

(*): Curiously, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> work just fine. There are other shortcuts that do not work either, but I'm less bothered by them, like <kbd>F4</kbd>-based ones (used by ChromeOS to maximize/restore windows) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.